# Emulator keep showing "Android"

Tags: android

I am new to android application.
i have downloaded Android Studio from http://developer.android.com/

I just created one project and click on run button.

but it just keep showing me from past 2 hours

what should i do now  ??

is there any step by step instruction that i can follow?

[image: jdkk]

Comment: Are you using intel haxm accelerator ?

Comment: I don'n know... how do i check it?

Comment: He is probably not using haxm, as the log states "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode". See Android guide for hardware acceleration on how to enable haxm: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm

Comment: Shifar Shifz link in the answer also contains information about using haxm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How we can speed up the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-we-can-speed-up-the-android-emulator)

Comment: Try creating a new AVD with a different device prototype. Do tell the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usual, there are some tricks to avoid this, see this [Why emulator is very slow in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732021/why-emulator-is-very-slow-in-android-studio),  and i use BlueStack for debugging. it's better than anything.