# Android studio: AVD ram size not changing?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio 1.3.2. When I run the app, I get the following event log:

```
f:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_One_API_23 -netspeed full -netdelay none

emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB

emulator: device fd:728

HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.

emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1024 MB

emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 768 MB

emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.

creating window 77 81 298 496

emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check.
```

I've already tried increasing the RAM size of AVD Nexus One to 512 MB and 768 MB. The same event log occurs for both.

Comment: try running HAXM from extras folder in your SDK and increasing RAM for it.

Comment: Why you are not using Genymotion instead of default avd : https://www.genymotion.com/#!/ OR check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732021/why-emulator-is-very-slow-in-android-studio

Comment: @rahul - i dont have the limit upto 1024 mb for HAXm as i hv only 2gb of ram .

Comment: then please try [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) as suggested in comment above.

Comment: @Haresh and Rahul - where to find apk file ?

Comment: YourProject/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade the Intel x86 Atom System Image to API-19 instead of API 21/22/23 so as to use less RAM space. You can find the config in the config.ini file, and set the RAM size to 512 by hw.ramSize=512.

I had tried Image with API-21/22/23. Even I had set ramSize=256 in config.ini, or add option to change the memory size, after the command: `emulator -memory 256 -avd [<avd_name>]`, it still shows: `emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB`