# How can I change the ram amount that the android emulator is using?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

at the first setup, Android Studio asked me that how much ram does the emulator going to use. I entered 800M but it worked slowly. I need to make it a little bit bigger like 1.5GB. How can I do that? Is it editable after the first setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why emulator is very slow in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732021/why-emulator-is-very-slow-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**My answer seems to be old, so for recent versions check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65685513/4935567)**

Go to `Tools->Android->AVD Manager`, there's something like pencil to edit your `AVD` click on that, then in the pop-up window click `Show Advanced Settings` and there you can change the `RAM` size.

Comment: I was testing my app's on the virtual device instead of Note 5 that has samsung modified Android. It was running so slow. Thank you so much.

Comment: **`Happy Coding`** `:)`

Comment: As I check, the RAM size and vm size are disabled for modification.

Comment: That does'nt worked

Answer (score 68):

I generated a Pixel 2 image in the past and those values were locked to match the HW default of `1536` MB, so to edit them I had to *"Show on disk"* (from ADV manager) and edit the `hw.ramSize` keys in `hardware-qemu.ini` and `config.ini`

Comment: That was what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this solution.

Comment: Also need to delete `hardware-qemu.ini.lock` file and let it get generated automatically by running the emulator again.

Comment: So weird that they don't let you edit the RAM of Google Play emulators in device manager, but this method works to increase the RAM

Answer (score 22):

- Create a new virtual device from the **AVD Manage**r.
- Select **New hardware profile**(left-bottom corner) in the appearing window.
- You can see an option **Memory** in the new secondly appeared window.
  Here you can change the **ram size** in the   column **RAM**.

Comment: The problem is already this. There is a minimum RAM setting in the emulator. I need to change this. Otherwise doing the thing you suggested with this answer is impossible. The first answer works.

Comment: Please note if you make a new profile you won't be able to choose a device with google play services

Answer (score 1):

or you can create a new hardware profile, that allows you to choose the amount of ram avaliable. Also you can change the number of CPU cores in the hardware-quemu.ini and config.ini on the device files.

Answer (score -2):

**For Mac Users,**

Go to **Android studio** -> **Tools** -> **Device Manager** -> **Select your AVD and click on 3 dots** -> **Edit** -> **Show Advance Setting** -> **Scroll down** -> **Memory and Storage** -> **Give the customize ram in Ram field** -> **click finish**.

**Also make sure to restart the device if its already running to reflect the changes!**