# Android Studio- ADV "System UI isn't responding"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

So I'm a beginner in Android Studio. I have created a Nexus S as an ADV. Every time I launch that device, it says "System UI isn't responding". I get 2 options; close app, wait.

When I click close, nothing happens but when I click wait, it just goes on as if nothing happened.

I was just wondering what I can do to get rid of this problem?
Also does increasing the RAM on the device make it any faster? Can I do anything to make it faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This caused because of the RAM size is small in my case.

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Select the device > Show Advanced Settings > Change the RAM.

If you can't edit the setting, then create new device.

related:

[How can I change the ram amount that the android emulator is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068344/how-can-i-change-the-ram-amount-that-the-android-emulator-is-using)
[The system ui isn't responding in android emulator (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371056/the-system-ui-isnt-responding-in-android-emulator-flutter)