# The system ui isn't responding in android emulator (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

After starting the avd in android studio, the system ui is not responding message comes in the android emulator. So, how can i fix it ?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16402304/9902765

Comment: This answer works well for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66753570/6180340

Comment: Long click on the Power icon until the android native reboot/shutdown overlay appears and click "Power Off" or "Restart"

Comment: Thanks @ccpizza! So far, your suggestion to long click the power icon is the *only* method that's worked for me so far.

Comment: I switched to API level 31 for this in react native. API level 31 works well in my case

Answer (score 124):

1.Open AVD Manager.
[image]
2.Click to edit button for your device.
[image]
3.Select Hardware in the Graphics drop down menu.
[image]

Comment: unfortunately this option is grayed out

Comment: Actually, this problem seems to be limited to devices with Play Store available, so Nexus 5X and Nexus 5 images will be forced to use Automatic Graphics, but all other devices allow you to choose either Automatic, Hardware or Software graphics.

Comment: It was grayed out but I changed the system image to x86-64 and now it works. I hope, it fixes this issue. It takes a time to check it.

Comment: any idea what is actual reason? is this an emulator issue or code?

Comment: Didn't work. My Issue was what Pouya Heydari told about  X86 & X86_64 versions...

Comment: If this option is grayed for you, just edit it directly in `config.ini` of your AVD. On Mac path would be: `$HOME/.android/avd/MyAvdName.avd/config.ini`. 

Change value of `hw.gpu.mode` from `auto` to `host` → `hw.gpu.mode=host`

Comment: Mine was greyed out so I deleted it and created a new one. Whatever time I may have lost by having to resetup a new device is easily worth the time lost using an unbearably slow emulator.

Comment: @Zain You can change it when creating a new device.

Comment: Using this option results in the emulator failing to open with the message **The emulator process for AVD Pixel_XL_API_33 has terminated.**

Comment: This doesn't really, even with X86_64 version. One thing that worked for me is wiping the data and cold booting, or sometimes just cold booting. Does anyone know why this error happens?

Answer (score 61):

I used to face this problem every time I started my AVD. Also the cold boot option was just a temporary fix for me.

I checked the android version that I had installed on my emulator, and noticed the **ABI version was x86**.

To fix that:

- Start creating a new android emulator
- in the system image section, **Select the X86_64** version

That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: The steps can be found in an other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67524561/8184729

Answer (score 35):

On OS X, I am able to solved it by steps:

Open Android Studio. Navigate to Configure > AVD Manager.
Under Actions > dropdown triangle on the right > Cold Boot Now:

Comment: Spot on for my case, yes.

Comment: This is a temporary mitigation, not a solution.

Comment: Worked on Linux as well.

Comment: Works temporarily

Comment: It does fixes but it's a temporary fix.

Comment: Solved in my case. Thanks.

Comment: right, you are basically rebooting your emulator, which is not a "solution" :)

Answer (score 35):

I was constantly annoyed by this and would often click on Wait, then realize after some time the tremendous amount of time wasted.

I fixed it by creating a new emulator (ctrl + shift + a -> "avd", select avd manager):

- Choose create new device, select Pixel 4 or Pixel 4 XL for example
- Then instead of selecting recommended system image, selected "API Level S, ABI x86_64 (former device was only x86), Target Android API S (Google Play). Beware it will be a 1.3GB download, and will take a little while. Finished? Click on Next.
- In advanced settings (show), increase RAM from 512 to 1024.

Now I don't have this problem anymore.

Comment: Increasing RAM helped me. I've also increased "hw.cpu.ncore" param by one

Answer (score 7):

I finally found what causes this in my case.
Once I resize, after a couple of minutes I got that error. So:

**DON'T RESIZE YOUR EMULATOR WINDOW** **!!!!**

I still got that message from time to time, but not that often.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 10, I just wiped the data from the emulator image and started it again. However, as Aadn commented below, this is only a **temporary** solution.

Comment: its a temporary fix for a few mins. Atleast in my case that is what happens.

Comment: Also set RAM to **2048** mb, keep **Software** graphics, and disable both **Multi-Core CPU** and **Device Frame**.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by navigating to the AVD Manager by

```
Tools > AVD Manager > Right Click the emulator > Wipe all data > Switch on the virtual device.
```

It worked for me just fine, you can also use it when you are troubleshooting the problem with the emulator in android studio.

Comment: Wipe all data was the key for me

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the emulator inside a VM (as I am) then your only option is probably to increase the number of cores the emulator can use.

Edit your device emulators `config.ini` file:

```
/home/${USER}/.android/avd/${DEVICE_NAME}.avd/config.ini
```

And increase the number of cores from the default of 2 to something higher. eg:

```
hw.cpu.ncore=6
```

Comment: This worked for me even though I'm not running inside a VM.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the latest system images and creating an emulator using that. My problem is gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking "**Stop**" just click on "**wait**" and the Emulator will work fine.

And If it is taking too much time in loading make sure you have installed the
"**HAXM installer**" in SDK tools , Also make sure "**Hyper V**" option is also unchecked in
"**Turn Windows features on or off**" in **Control Panel** --> **Program and features**.

Only After unchecking this feature you can install the HAXM installer.

After doing this the Emulator will not take time to load , but still it can show the **error** "**System UI isn't responding**", as I told in starting just click on "**wait**" and it will run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66265270/5128831

> It seems even though intel HAXM shows as installed on SDK Tools, it
> wasnt really installed so i had to go to below location and manually
> reinstall (intelhaxm-android) file.
>
> ```
> C:\Users\SUHAIL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
> ```
>
> if the file doesnt exist in that location, that means it wasnt
> downloaded and you will have to download the file online

Answer (score 0):

Change RAM of your emulator to bigger value. That's works for me)

Answer (score -1):

[image: Change your Graphics]

[image: Click wipe Data]

Just follow this instruction hope it will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

You can download "Google APIs intel x86 atom_64 system image" from your sdk manager of your android version.
This technique worked for me!!

Answer (score -1):

Changing of the emulator API. That's what helped me. It's better to try different ones. I've got the 31 one.

Nothing else worked for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).