# Android Studio 4.1.1 "System UI isn't responding " Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUx3X.jpg)

[I can't change performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwfSh.jpg)

**I just started to get this error and I don't know to fix it. I saw others questions and some of them fixed it with changing performance but I can't change the performance, as you can see in second picture. What should I do?**

Comment: Are you getting this in an Emulator or a physical device?

Comment: in an Emulator, but now I fixed it thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't change emulated performance of AVD in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328225/cant-change-emulated-performance-of-avd-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

API 30, when you make a new emulator in the tab "x86 images" which is near "Recommended", **download system image x86-64**, instead of system image x86. This solution helped me

Comment: Tried it and though it's still slow, it's definitely faster for me. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up "Graphics-Hardware" by installing a new emulator. If you have intel processor. Make sure Intel HAXM is installed. It may provide a solution to lower the resolution adjustment.

Comment: I deleted old emulator and installed new one, everything is same as old emulator but now it is working thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If marked as the correct answer, someone else will help.

Answer (score 0):

If Intel HAXM is installed, it will fix. One solution might be to lower the resolution setting.