# Android Emulator not responding - frozen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

when i try to launch AVD in emulator a small window appears (see image) and after 5 second it says not responding and stays that way until i close it.

i searched online and tried all solutions but non worked

- virtualization is enabled in BIOS
- HAXM is installed
- tried running with a lower virtual device ram
- changed emulated performance to Hardware - GLES 2.0 and Software - GLES 2.0. non worked
- dont have hyper V installed on my WIN10

i dont know what else i can try, please help if you can.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so it seems even though intel HAXM shows as installed on SDK Tools, it wasnt really installed so i had to go to below location and manually reinstall (intelhaxm-android) file.

C:\Users\SUHAIL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

if the file doesnt exist in that location, that means it wasnt downloaded and you will have to download the file online

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me. The folder was present `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` but apparently HAXM did not install correctly. I manually ran the `haxm-7.6.5-setup.exe` from that folder and it said it was already installed but asked if I wanted to continue anyway; I said "yes!" and it reinstalled. Now the Android emulators run. I also noticed the progress bar immediately after launching an emulated device is animated, whereas before reinstalling HAXM it did not animate (and soon said "(Not Responding)" in the titlebar).

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was Visual Studio Xamarin and Android Studio installations probably interfering with each other. So, I completely removed both of them with no left over files and registry. Afterwards installing only Android Studio withcorresponding SDK tools and accelerator solved my problem. I haven't installed VS Xamarin (MAUI) again, as it may break things again.