# Getting error while running program on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am running program on Android Studio and getting below error. Can you please help:

20:14   Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

20:14   Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1536M too high for your system. Reducing to maximum supported size 512M

20:14   Emulator: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-i386.exe: Could not load library WinHvPlatform.dll.

20:14   Emulator: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-i386.exe: failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented

Answer (score 0):

While installing Android studio you might've set the size of RAM for your Emulator to **1536MB** which is high, as mentioned in the Warning.

Please follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068344/how-can-i-change-the-ram-amount-that-the-android-emulator-is-using) to reduce the Allocated size for Emulator.

If you have a RAM of 4GB on your system (I'm guessing it, because you got this warning), please run the app on your physical phone itself, instead of the Emulator.

Another option is to use: ***Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)*** which might / might not help you.