# Android emulators bugs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

lately I am facing some troubles with my android emulators, some of them start but never work, others start and after several minutes my pc crashes and others do not start at all.

Any solutions? Like turn it off and on? or just restart your computer when something bad happen?

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Install more RAM. Or close Chrome. (It eats up all your RAM). Make sure you have hardware acceleration turned on. Stop running bad things in the emulators. Anyways, your question is way too generic for StackOverflow :-(

Comment: I have 32 GB ram and I never use Chrome :P

Comment: This question is like "My application doesnt work, please help!!!". Please provide more details with your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the ram amount that the android emulator is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068344/how-can-i-change-the-ram-amount-that-the-android-emulator-is-using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your RAM is below 8GB then you want to consider upgrading your
   RAM.
2. Run one emulator at a time. Sometimes you might get frustrated and
   therefore starting up two at a time, this will slow down your system
   and the emulator performance as well. Solution for this is run a
   system task manager check to see all running process then terminate
   the unnecessary processes running.
3. Finally, if the above don't help; I will suggest you download
   **Bluestack Android Emulator** as that is so much kin to work with and
   reliable.

[Download Bluestack here](https://bluestacks-app-player.mrdownload.com/en/for-windows/app/?dlurl=https://www.bluestacks.com/download.html&gclid=Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAUsCjAKQACbPNrrIeIddaP9tfX7X2ISi7G3WqYf39u_p5Xa5Iky_IaAuRHEALw_wcB)

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response, my Ram is 32Gb and usually I run one a emulator at a time, so I will try the 3rd solution and I will let you know If I am happy with the result :D

Comment: Okay Prodromos Sarakinou

Comment: I am more than happy with blue stack, thank you :)